# How to pass <textarea> value to function in controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need the value of `address` in a function which is in a controller in JS file. How can I get this value? It's not in a form, its in a `<div>` tag.

```html
<textarea class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Type your Address" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: if your using `angularjs` then use `ng-model` and go through some exercises before u start if u newer to `angularjs`. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="textContent" placeholder="Type your Address" rows="5"></textarea>
```

In your controller access with help of scope

```
 function ctrl($scope){

      console.log($scope.textContent);
    }
```

Comment: I want to JK but my reputation is 14

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-model` in your `textarea` like this,

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="details" name="address" placeholder="Type your Address" rows="5"></textarea>
```

then in controller you can access it like,

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.dir($scope.details);
});
```

Take a look into [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) here from the official angularjs docs. 
You know what, its damn cool!